# How to configure aws cli on ubuntu gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, aws-cli

While trying to install and configure aws cli on ubuntu runner in pipeline, stuck at below screen.

[pipeline stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc0v7.png)

How to do that?

Comment: You likely need to set some environment variables before this step. Something like `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` and `TZ=America/New_York`.

Answer (score -1):

This might be helpful. https://medium.com/@shashim.author/aws-command-not-found-in-gitlab-ci-yml-958c964e007c [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@shashim.author/aws-command-not-found-in-gitlab-ci-yml-958c964e007c)